# Kendo UI DatePicker Does Not Set Value After Change Event Run

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have two Kendo UI DatePicker objects on the page. Both of them had been set with a function called in `document.ready()`. After change event runs when date changed the same function that was called from document.ready() runs again. But this time first datepicker object does not set the value. I used it like below

```
var endPicker = $("#endDate").data("kendoDatePicker");
var beginPicker = $("#startDate").data("kendoDatePicker");
if ($("#today").is(':checked')) {
 beginPicker.value(new Date());//this one sets null not the date
 endPicker.value(new Date());
}
```

Something prevents setting the first datepicker's value. Change events only for validating date range and start and end datepickers call them respectively

```
 function startChange() {
        var endPicker = $("#endDate").data("kendoDatePicker"),
            first = this.value();

        if (first) {
            first = new Date(first);
            first.setDate(first.getDate() + 1);
            endPicker.min(first);
        }
        dateChanged();//calls ajax
    }

    function endChange() {
        var startPicker = $("#startDate").data("kendoDatePicker"),
            second = this.value();

        if (second) {
            second = new Date(second);
            second.setDate(second.getDate() - 1);
            startPicker.max(second);
        }
        dateChanged();//calls ajax
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah finally I found what was wrong and why first datepicker can not set today's value. It's all about second datepicker's change event. It sets it's own value -1 as the first datepicker's max value. So it should be written as `second.setDate(second.getDate());` In this case they set `new Date()` as their new value.